# JPA Lookup Table Values

Tags: java, database, jpa, lookup

I've got 2 tables. One for questions and one for possible answers. For example, I'm modelling:
"Do you own a dog?"  Yes[ ], No[ ].

So I have a set of questions and a set of possible answers. What I want to know how do I represent this in JPA (note this is not about capturing the answer, but displaying the question and populating a selection box).

So far I have:

```
@Entity(name="QUESTIONS")
public class Question {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private int order;
  private String questionTitle;
  private String questionText;
  private Set<AnswerOption> possibleAnswers;
  ....
}
```

It is the `private Set<AnswerOption> possibleAnswers;` part I'm having trouble with. How do I get this to be pre-populated with the possible range of answers?

The way it is modelled above will provide a Set variable to store answers in.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Should I use code to populate the database and assign the same AnswerOption object(s) to different Question objects?

Thanks for any help.
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hibernate is essentially an ORM tool, it just takes care of mapping your `Question` and `AnswerOption` classes and instances to the defined tables.

What *you* need is to initialize **data**, not data *structure*. So, you've got to populate all of your `Question` instances with their possible `AnswerOption` instances in some sort of `initQuestions()` initialization method.

Also, you'd better note whether these `Question`s are already initialized.

Comment: Super answer thank you very much. This is how I done it. Firstly I used `@Transactional` methods to set-up the look-up date (answer options). Then I used `@Transactional` methods to set-up the questions and and join them to a set of possible answers.

The thing to look out for is than in the `Question` class you have to use a `@ManyToMany` join to your possible set of answers. I got a bit confused because I was using a `@OneToMany` (this question can have many answers), but was being a bit dumb because the `answerOption` can also appear on many questions. Duh. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this first from a database relational modeling point of view, before trying to map that relationship in JPA. First, you need to define how questions and answers are linked at the database level. I presume you use a foreign key or association table. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    text VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE answers (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    text VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE question_answers (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    question_id INT NOT NULL,
    answer_id INT NOT NULL,
    KEY k_question_id (question_id),
    KEY k_answer_id (answer_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_question_answers_question_id FOREIGN KEY (question_id)
        REFERENCES questions(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_question_answers_answer_id FOREIGN KEY (answer_id)
        REFERENCES answers(id)
);
```

This defines the relationship between questions and answers as an association table, which you can then map in JPA thusly:

```
@Entity(name="QUESTIONS")
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private int order;
    private String questionTitle;
    private String questionText;

    @JoinTable(name = "question_answers", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", unique = true) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id") })
    private Set<AnswerOption> possibleAnswers;
}
```

The annotations for using a foreign key (as opposed to an association table) will be different of course, if you want to go that route leave a comment and I'll whip up an example. This should be enough to get you started.